# Retrieving large database table data

Tags: c#, database, oracle, data-migration

I feel like this is a stupid question but I've been searching for a couple days and I have not found a useful answer.

I'm building a batch job style C# program that will be used to keep two databases (1 Oracle (10g) and 1 SQL Server) in sync as we transition over to using the SQL Server database.

My question is how do I iterate over all the records in a particular database table. The table (34 columns) has about 200k records. My code below seems to retrieve only 74 records (I presume this is some sort of memory limit?) how do I process these 74 records and then iterate over the next 74 say? I cannot seem to find any process to do this? This strikes me as so strange as surely people have encountered this kind of issue all time.

Code:

```
    using (OracleConnection OraCon = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sourceDatabase"].ConnectionString))
    {
        var command = new OracleCommand(SqlConstants.AppUserFindAllSql, OraCon)
        {
            CommandType = CommandType.Text
        };

        var dataTable = new DataTable("AppUser");

        OraCon.Open();

        using (var oracleReader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            dataTable.Load(oracleReader);
        }
    }
```

SqlConstants.AppUserFindAllSql:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   APP_USER 
ORDER BY
   USER_ID
```

Note that it is not actually '*' in the query but there is no point in listing all 34 columns as it is not relevant.

Comment: X-Y-Question, IMHO. Syncing the Tables is a bad idea to start with. Better create a View in SQL-Server that will relay to Oracle and later just switch to a Table on SQL Server. (Basic Idea - without knowing what you are doing exactly.)

Comment: Start by NOT USING DATA TABLES but iterating over the recordset?

Comment: @TomTom could you give me an example please?

Comment: Nope, too broad or too basic. It is in the documentation and there are TONS of tutorials not using datatables.

Comment: That suggests you're going to review every row in the source table each time your code is run - and presumably do a row by row comparison to see if it's in the destination table. Consider adding a processed flag to the source table which defaults to 0 and is set to 1 when it's migrated. Then you need only look at non-processed rows.